# What type of pedal are these?

Tags: pedals

My son bought a bicycle with these clipless pedals and is hoping to find the appropriate cleats.  What pedal model are they?[image]

Comment: You might do better to simply buy new pedals, which will come with one pair of cleats.

Answer (score 7):

Nice bike!

They are single-sided SPD pedals, made by Ritchey, compatible with the common 2-bolt mountain SPD cleat.  Note that there are two different, much larger road SPD cleats (SPD-SL ), that are not compatible with these.

https://products.roadbikereview.com/product/drivetrain/pedals/ritchey/logic-pro-28052.html

Answer (score 5):

[image]

(note the numbers refer to the image dimensions -- both cleats are the same size)

They are older road/touring pedals that use the shimano SPD standard.

Shimano, LOOK and other SPD 2-bolt standard cleats will fit

Comment: I've never heard about 2-bolt SPD compatible Look cleats

Comment: I guess those numbers aren't the dimensions - 1200✕1200 mm would be a very big pedal!

Comment: @ojs new for 2019

Comment: @toby lol just a convenient screenshot with model numbers and image res!

Comment: @ojs https://www.lookcycle.com/us-en/products/pedals/mtb/cleats/cleat-x-track

Answer (score 2):

The early clipless Shimano pedals were licensed copies of Look Delta. When they brought out the SPD type for MTB it was followed shortly by tiny Ultegra and Dura-Ace models with MTB cleats. They disappeared quickly from the market. Mainly because the range of available road shoes for two-bolt cleats was limited and the tiny contact surface put too much pressure on the soles.

Your pedals are compatible with SPD mountain cleats. Buy the ones with uni-directional release to avoid unexpected untimely release.

A word of caution: Be aware that when used with thicker soled MTB shoes, the pedals will sit deeper in the soles which in turn could hinder a smooth and safe release. Shims under the cleats could be required. In any case, check for easy and safe release before entering traffic.

[image]

Comment: These should release as cleanly if not more so than current MTB SPDs (slightly more to interfere than M520, much  less than M324/M424).  If they don't, rather than shimming, which defeats the purpose of choosing SPDs over road cleats, trim away the interfering material.  But absolutely test somewhere safer - they could be far stiffer than you're expecting if they've not been used in a while,

Comment: @ChrisH: it lives on today as PD-A600 ULTEGRA SPD ROAD TOURING PEDALS

Comment: My mental block on Ultegra and other expensive lines clearly stopped me from seeing the newer equivalents  (but actually I prefer the way M520s are always the right way up)